# Trying to detect video card gpu temp but cant add reference nvcpl.dll getting error "could not be added"

Tags: c#, nvidia

I want to detect my video card gpu temperature.
So i wanted to use nvcpl.dll add it as reference to my code.

Im using visual studio 2010 express and windows 7.

I found the file nvcpl.dll in: C:\Windows\System32
But when im trying to add the file as reference im ggeting the error:

" A reference to d:\nvcpl.dll could not be added. Please make make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component "

I tried also to copy first the file to d:\
I tried examples and codes samples in google.

Cant figure out how to use the dll then.

Comment: I guess that nvcpl.dll is a native DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find working source code in C# that gets the GPU temprature (and so much more) from the [Open Hardware Monitor](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/) project at http://code.google.com/p/open-hardware-monitor/

> Open Hardware Monitor
>
> The Open Hardware Monitor is a free open source software that monitors
>   temperature sensors, fan speeds, voltages, load and clock speeds of a
>   computer.
>
> The Open Hardware Monitor supports most hardware monitoring chips
>   found on todays mainboards. The CPU temperature can be monitored by
>   reading the core temperature sensors of Intel and AMD processors. The
>   sensors of ATI and Nvidia video cards as well as SMART hard drive
>   temperature can be displayed. The monitored values can be displayed in
>   the main window, in a customizable desktop gadget, or in the system
>   tray. The Open Hardware Monitor software runs on 32-bit and 64-bit
>   Microsoft Windows XP / Vista / 7 and any x86 based Linux operating
>   systems without installation.

<strike>You need to user interop similar to the example code here:
http://www.mp3car.com/coders-corner/107386-vb-net-screenorientation-angle180.html</strike>

From the nvidia API docs that I could quickly find ([PDF from 2005](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=17&ved=0CGIQFjAGOAo&url=http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/9.5/Samples/DEMOS/common/src/NvCpl/docs/NVControlPanel_API.pdf&ei=We73Tspk0uzYBZ7o-LsC&usg=AFQjCNHfKwHX8DXNY0QI0uOdpakP8JJn3w)) it looks like the call you actually need is:

**NvCplGetThermalSettings()**

Function Prototype

```
BOOL CDECL NvCplGetThermalSettings
(IN UINT nWindowsMonitorNumber,
OUT DWORD* pdwCoreTemp,
OUT DWORD* pdwAmbientTemp,
OUT DWORD* pdwUpperLimit);
```

Parameters In UINT nWindowsMonitorNumber -- The display number shown on
the Windows Display Properties->Settings page.

A value of 0 indicates the current primary Windows display device.

- DWORD* must be a valid pointer --
- pdwCoreTemp -- GPU temperature in degrees Celsius.
- pdwAmbientTemp -- Ambient temperature in degrees Celsius.
- pdwUpperLimit -- Upper limit of the GPU temperature specification.

Return Values True on success.
False on failure.